# Sending JSON from Android to Nodejs server

Tags: java, android, node.js

I try to send a request from an Android device to a Nodejs server using

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(IP + "/getrestaurant")).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.connect();
con.getOutputStream().write("{'restaurant_id':'569a16e28dcdc5c8add2a8e0'}".getBytes("UTF-8"));
con.getOutputStream().flush();
con.getOutputStream().close();
```

When I print the received request from node js I get:

```
{          
  "{'restaurant_id':'569a16e28dcdc5c8add2a8e0'}": ""
}
```

instead of `{'restaurant_id':'569a16e28dcdc5c8add2a8e0'}`

How can I get it work? Thanks!

Comment: `{'restaurant_id':'569a16e28dcdc5c8add2a8e0'}` is not valid json ...

Answer (score 0):

as the comment says(i have too low reputation to comment), {'restaurant_id':'569a16e28dcdc5c8add2a8e0'} is not valid context

also I advice you to use Koush Ion library for json requests . https://github.com/koush/ion

It is very convenient and easy to use for , give it a try . In one line all types of requests are done ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`